# Scroll bar for only one column in grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have divided the page into two equal column by bootstrap grid.. I want scroll bar for the column 1 and Not for the entire page.. In column 1 I have grid view for graphs and in column 2 layout I only one table.

I want to know how to add scroll bar for column1 alone and not for the entire page.

The problem I am facing is i get scroll bar for the entire page eventhough I gave overflow:auto to column1 div

code:
html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row first-row">
    <!-- left column - plot area  -->
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 column1" >
        <div class="btn-groups button-align">
                <button class="btn pull-right" onclick="listView()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> List</button> 
                <button class="btn pull-right active" onclick="gridView()"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> Grid</button>
        </div>
           <div class="plot-area">
            <div class="container-fluid second-row">
                <div class="row">
```

css :

```
.second-row{
       overflow:auto;
    }
    .col-md-6.column1{ 
       background-color:black; 
       overflow-y: auto; 
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: what is the use case when second column height is more than display size? If it is more then again there will be scrollbar to entire page.

Comment: how to make second column size as same as display page..that it should not lead to scroll bar

Answer (score 1):

You need to set max height to trigger an overflow, also set overflow to scroll.
Here is an edited code snippet.

```
.second-row{
        overflow:auto;
     }
     .col-md-6.column1{ 
        max-height: 500px;
        background-color:black; 
        overflow: scroll; 
         padding: 0 0 0 0;
   }
```

Comment: how to make the entire page scroll bar removed. I want to show the content within the page

Comment: and aslo if i mention the max-height in percentage its not working

Comment: 1. Page scrollbar will not show if elements fit the visible height of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "vh" as follows if percentage is not working:

```
.col-md-6.column1{ 
    max-height: 70vh;
    background-color:black; 
    overflow: auto; 
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
```

}

And in order to remove scrollbar from entire "body" of a page you need to add "overflow:hidden" to it e.g.

```
body{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: "vh" calculates height in percentage with respect to screen size. and you can change 70vh value  from 1 to 100

Comment: make sure that you are making body{overflow:hidden} may impact your all project if you change it in common stylesheet. So will suggest you to add it on that page element "body" tag in inline manner.